# Swf resource consumption optimization

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a page, which displays two big flash movies (not simultaneously) and switches from one to another quite often without reloading the page. I have started with hiding one movie and displaying another. Like

```
$('#flash1').css('display', 'none');
$('#flash2').css('display', 'block');
```

In Mozilla it was ok, as flash1 stopped working and was loaded once again when switching back to flash1. But in IE and Chrome flash continued to work, which caused some lagging. I have tried many things, but the only one successful is to remove unused flash completely like this:

```
$('#flash1').html('');
$('#flash2').html('html code of flash');
```

The only thing which confuses me, that flash movies have to be reloaded each time, which causes a little pause when switching from one flash to another, and I think that it would be better if both flashes are loaded all the time, and somehow stopped when not used. Is there any solution to do this or it is better to do like I did it?

Comment: I'm not into HTML/JS that much but... As you say its better for the SWFs to stop whatever they are doing and go to "sleep mode" when not in use... For that you should have coded the SWfs to receive a "sleep" event from javascript and react accordingly. If you cant change SWF code (you need source files) then you could try "hiding" unused SWF behind a background layer using CSS layers, hopefully the browswer might be clever enough to let CPU usage go down since not visible, I know CPU usage can go down if you switch tabs away from Flash content tab so...

Comment: I have tried something like this, but it didn't help enough. But seems like I will try to do anything else this way.